# Markov Chain (Reverse Process)

Tags: probability, markov-chains

> > Question: After the season has ended, $5\%$ of all Soccer  players convert to Basketball, and $20\%$ of all Basketball players convert to Soccer League. If there are A Soccer players at the start of the $2016$ season, how many Soccer players must start the $2016$ season in order for the number of Soccer and Basketball to be unchanged at the start of the $2017$ season (in terms of $A$)?

I have set up my transition matrix as such

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
        0.95 & 0.2        \\[0.3em]
       0.05& 0.8          \\[0.3em]
     \end{bmatrix}$

Since I'm not sure how to format this on latex the matrix should have titles like this: [image]

However after setting up the transition matrix, I'm having trouble completing the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is the amount of soccer players and B the amount of basketball players, you can use the following:

$$
\Bigg[
 \begin{matrix}
  0.95 & 0.2 \\
  0.05 & 0.8
 \end{matrix}
\Bigg]
\Bigg[
 \begin{matrix}
  A \\
  B
 \end{matrix}
\Bigg]
=
\Bigg[
\begin{matrix}
  A \\
  B
\end{matrix}
\Bigg]
\iff
\begin{cases}
0.95A + 0.2B = A\\
0.05A + 0.8B = B
\end{cases}
\iff B = \frac{A}{4}$$

Comment: Doesn't $A+B=1$ have to be satisfied as well so you can find a numerical value for $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @dydxx No, $A$ can be any positive integer value (divisible by 20 because of the factor $0.05$). Without further information, it is not possible to know the actual amount of players (other than that it equals $\frac{5A}{4}$).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to look at this: since 5% of the Soccer Players must equal 20% of Basketball players, there must be 4 times as many Soccer Players as Basketball players.